# Removing labels from a basemap

Tags: labeling, basemap, arcgis-online-basemaps

I've made a nice roadmap and am trying to add a basemap, but the World Topo Map has town names, so does the USA Topo map and the Nat Geo Topo map. how do I get rid of these?

Comment: You can't as far as I'm aware. Labels and topographic features are part of the same layer

Comment: Are they a part of the layer or are they a label/annotation feature?

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about ESRI Basemaps, the basemaps usually comes with 2 layers, a reference layer, and the basemap itself. Turning off the reference layer turns off most labels.

Comment: Unfortunately these maps don't have a separate reference layer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to getting rid of the labels in Basemaps added to ArcMap that don't have separate reference layer labels?

If so, you can just add the map service layer directly to your map instead of importing the base map from the Add Data button.

So for example, to add the World Street Base map to ArcMap without the labels, go to Add ArcGIS Server, select use GIS services, and add this link: 
http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Terrain_Base/MapServer. Then add the World Terrain Base to your map (It looks similar to the World Street Base map, just without the labels).

Check out the other basemaps here to see if you can find a version without labels to add for the basemap you want: http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me - quick, easy and perfect!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to remove or modify basemap labels as they are part of the imagery. However, it is possible to use a basemap with less labels or customize a vector basemap to meet the desired specification.

GO through with the link,
[FAQ: Is it possible to remove basemap labels in ArcGIS Online?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000019873)

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this question I wanted to use the World Street Map without place name labels in ArcPro. I was able to achieve this by loading a pre-built Vector Tile Layer directly from the ArcGIS Online portal via the catalog Pane.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -3):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQ0pMKq7bB4

It is quite easy, in fact. This person shared this and it works fine for my needs.